# Java default method in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I try to convert following method to Kotlin but don't know the equivalent syntax.
The full class can be found [here](https://github.com/cockroachlabs/roach-data/blob/master/roach-data-jdbc/src/main/java/io/roach/data/jdbc/AccountController.java). Not sure we can implement this in kolin.

```
@GetMapping("/account")
    @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
    public HttpEntity<PagedModel<AccountModel>> listAccounts(
            @PageableDefault(size = 5, direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) Pageable page) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok(pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(accountRepository.findAll(page), accountModelAssembler()));
    }

 private RepresentationModelAssembler<Account, AccountModel> accountModelAssembler() {
        return (entity) -> {
            AccountModel model = new AccountModel();
            model.setName(entity.getName());
            model.setType(entity.getType());
            model.setBalance(entity.getBalance());
            model.add(linkTo(methodOn(AccountController.class)
                    .getAccount(entity.getId())
            ).withRel(IanaLinkRelations.SELF));
            return model;
        };
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a `default` method (a method implemented in an interface) here; what exactly is the part you are not sure how to translate? The Annotations?

Comment: The second method please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code in Kotlin:

```
@GetMapping("/account")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
fun listAccounts(@PageableDefault(size = 5, direction = Direction.ASC) page: Pageable?):
        HttpEntity<PagedModel<AccountModel?>?>? {
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok(pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(accountRepository.findAll(page), accountModelAssembler()))
}

private fun accountModelAssembler(): RepresentationModelAssembler<Account, AccountModel> {
    return RepresentationModelAssembler<Account, AccountModel> { entity: Account ->
        val model = AccountModel()
        model.name = entity.name
        model.type = entity.type
        model.balance = entity.balance
        model.add(linkTo(methodOn(AccountController::class.java).getAccount(entity.id)).withRel(IanaLinkRelations.SELF))
        model
    }
}
```

Of course, I am not aware of some of your classes, so there is a chance it won't compile. Some things are very close to Java, but to understand others you need to be familiar with Kotlin :)

Comment: If you want to make that more idiomatic, you could replace the `model` temporary variable with a call to `.apply { … }`, and use an expression body to avoid specifying the return type.  And you could probably either use `it` instead of the `entity` parameter, or remove the explicit type parameters.  But those are veering into matters of style rather than correctness!

Answer (score 1):

To convert java code into kotlin code in a fast way, you need to open the .java file that you want to convert to kotlin.

Go to **Code(menu) / click on Convert Java File to Kotlin File**

This will automatically convert your java code into kotlin code.

Answer (score 1):

For me the shortest way is to copy the Java code and paste it in Kotlin file of the IDE. And the IDE (Android Studio / IntelliJ) will do the rest. This might face some issues to convert the code. For that case you have to fix those manually.